# Ubuntu Server as (and) Router?

Tags: server, router

Is it stable use Ubuntu as router and server (ssh, database backup, web server, etc)

thanks

Comment: Yes, that is what I do.

Comment: I mean, one pc server as router and server?

Comment: Yes, that is what I do. However, Andrews answer is right, as most consider it more secure to separate the router function from the other server functions. My main server is the router, web server, dns server, samba file server, and probably some stuff I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

It is stable to run Ubuntu as a router and server. However, most businesses prefer to have their servers behind a router because this, in most cases, improves security.